# Uncaught ReferenceError: student is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, deployment

the problem is i want the result like this

[image]

but it does not show it

what i want is to make a program that show names on webpage as i add them through the input box using array

it's a very easy program but i don't whay do i get this error

This is the code :

```js
var students = [];

document
  .getElementById("add-student-btn")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    var SNNA1me = document.getElementById("student-input").value;
    student.push(SNNA1me);
    document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = students;
  });
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px">
  <input type="text" id="student-input" />
  <button id="add-student-btn">Submit</button>
  <div id="students" style="font-size: 30px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a typo. `students` instead of `student`.

Answer (score 1):

`student.push(SNNA1me)` should be `students.push(SNNA1me)`

Answer (score 0):

Because your `student` is undefined
Correction should be

```
    var students = [];
       document.getElementById("add-student-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var SNNA1me = document.getElementById("student-input").value;
    students.push(SNNA1me);
    document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = students;
  });
```